# SQL Server improve query performance #Temp Table, Bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on an old auditing stored procedure that is taking a long time to get data causing timeouts on the system. We have managed to get the time down from over 20 minutes to running just over a minute, this is still too long.

I am running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

My question is is there anything I could do to improve the speed of the query? In particular the temporary tables and the a bulk insert statement.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].PK_ID,
    + every other value in the table (all values required)
INTO
    #temp5
FROM 
    dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail]
```

An `INNER JOIN` then occurs on `dbo.[Audit Register]` another select occurs and added to another temporary table `#result` is created.

Result temporary table gets the old and new result values for comparison. Below I have provided what event occurs on `#temp5`. Note these are just snippets; the stored procedure is way too big to post everything.

```
SELECT 
    RED.[FK_RegisterID],
    total of a 106 rows are selected here :( 
FROM
    #temp5 AS RED
LEFT JOIN 
    #temp5 AS OLD ON RED.IdentityColumn = OLD.IdentityColumn
LEFT JOIN
    [Audit Register] AS REG ON REG.PK_ID = RED.FK_RegisterID

SELECT MAX(PK_ID) 
OVER (PARTITION BY FK_RegisterID) AS MAX_PK_ID
FROM #temp5

DROP TABLE #temp5
```

The second part of my question is a bulk insert into this table created at the very top of the stored procedure

```
DECLARE @AuditOverView TABLE 
(
   FK_RegisterID INT,
   Audit_Date DATETIME,
   ContextUser NVARCHAR(30),
   Original_Value NVARCHAR(255),
   New_Value NVARCHAR(255),
   Assay NVARCHAR(200),
   Inst NVARCHAR(40),
   LotLevel NVARCHAR(3),
   Lot_ExpiryDate NVARCHAR(10),
   Lot_Number NCHAR(50),
   Audit_Type NVARCHAR(10),
   Partnumber INT,
   [Type] NVARCHAR(50),
   SubType NVARCHAR(50)
 )
```

The insert statement below:

```
INSERT INTO @AuditOverView 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        t.FK_RegisterID,
        t.Audit_Date,
        t.ContextUser,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Original_Date_Run, 127) AS Original_Value,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, New_Date_Run, 127) AS New_Value,
        t.Assay AS 'Assay',
        Instrument AS 'Inst',
        '1' AS 'LotLevel',
        Lot1_Expiry_Date AS 'Lot_ExpiryDate',
        Lot1Number AS 'Lot_Number',
        t.Audit_Type,
        part_number AS Partnumber,
        'QC Result' AS [Type],
        'Result Date' AS SubType
    FROM
        #Result AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT MAX(Audit_Date) AS DATE, FK_RegisterID
         FROM #Result
         GROUP BY FK_RegisterID) dt ON t.FK_RegisterID = dt.FK_RegisterID
                                    AND t.Audit_Date = dt.DATE
    WHERE 
        RTRIM(Lot1Number) != ''
        AND (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Original_Date_Run, 120) != CONVERT(NVARCHAR, New_Date_Run, 120)
            OR t.Audit_Type = 'i'
            OR t.Audit_Type = 'd')
```

This insert statement occurs about 50 times and the only line changes occur are:

```
'Result Date' AS SubType
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Original_Date_Run, 120) != CONVERT(NVARCHAR, New_Date_Run, 120)
```

I can provide more information if needed. Any help would be much appreciated to improve performance.

Comment: I understand your SP is long,Could you please post the execution plan in form of xml for the stored proc involved.further going through the code pasted above doesnt help in understanding where is the issue and what is the issue..please also check here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There are a couple of things that appear to be potential performance problems here. First is you are creating a temp table using a select with no where clause. That means you have to create a copy of the entire table with no conditions. Just use the base table instead. Secondly you are using a table variable. If this contains a lot of rows is can get incredibly slow. There isn't a magic number but generally somewhere around 5-10k rows the performance is noticeably worse. You have a number of nonSARGable predicates in your where clause. That happens when you use functions around column names.

Comment: On top of what @Sean Lange said. consider adding indexes to temp tables if you don't have any. Add them after data has been loaded into a table.

Comment: Thanks for the comments i will take them on board and try and get this beast running faster.

Comment: Look for temp db space

Comment: I assume because it is OLD SP it worked much faster when it was written. Right? That means your `[Audit Result Entry Detail]` is growing and makes process slower. Ask yourself if you can limit an amount of data to be compared. For instance: for only last month.

Comment: Using table variables rather than temporary tables is an extremely bad idea. Without a primary key or an index makes table variables worse. Second: `SELECT DISTINCT` will have to verify for every row whether there is a duplicate row that was already selected. A lot of times the `DISTINCT` signifies bad query design. If you can rewrite your query to guarantee no duplicate rows, you can drop the `DISTINCT` and have a much better performing query.